# I cannot figure out why this while loop is endless

Tags: c++, function, loops, while-loop

Here is the code I am currently working with:

```
bool playCraps(int currentGame, bool detailPrint, char isBetting, int startingBet)
{
    bool crapsResult = NULL;
    int currentGameStorage[100];
    int currentRoll = 1;
    int point = roll2Dice();
    int printingNumber = 0;
    currentGameStorage[0] = point;
    if(point == 7 || point == 11)
    {
        crapsResult = true;
    }
    else if(point == 2 || point == 3 || point == 12)
    {
        crapsResult = false;
    }
    else
    {
        crapsResult = NULL;
    }
    while(crapsResult != true || crapsResult != false)
    {
        currentGameStorage[currentRoll] = roll2Dice();
        if(currentGameStorage[currentRoll] == point)
        {
            crapsResult = true;
        }
        else if(currentGameStorage[currentRoll] == 7)
        {
            crapsResult = false;
        }
        currentRoll += 1;
    }
    currentRoll -= 1;
    if(detailPrint == true)
    {
        cout << "Game " << currentGame << ": ";
        for(printingNumber = 0; printingNumber <= currentRoll; printingNumber += 1)
        {
            cout << currentGameStorage[printingNumber] << " ";
        }
        if(crapsResult == true)
        {
            cout << "win";
        }
        else if(crapsResult == false)
        {
            cout << "lose";
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
    return crapsResult;
}
```

Whenever I run it it creates am emdless loop with no text appearing in the terminal. The function roll2Dice() simulates the roll of two six sided dice using the rand() function and adds the two results together. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Think about what `while(crapsResult != true || crapsResult != false)` means,

Comment: I set it to an and loop instead, but now there is an issue with my output. It is supposed to output every value in the array, but now it outputs one long negative number as opposed to a list of numbers between 1 and 12

Answer (score 2):

Your while test, `crapsResult != true || crapsResult != false` is necessarily true, and therefore does not terminate. The `crapsResult` value is either true of false, which will make one of the two halves of the expression true, and one false.  Both `true || false` and `false || true` evaluate to  `true`.

Answer (score 1):

As others have noted it's pretty obvious why the loop never ends.

Your use of NULL makes me think you wish you could have a bool which could hold three values (unset, true and false). You could achieve this with minimal changes by using a pointer to bool, but that's pretty disgusting. Enums are what you really need:

```
enum CrapsResult
{
    unrolled,
    true_result,
    false_result
};
```

The pertinent code then becomes*:

```
CrapsResult crapsResult = unrolled;
int currentGameStorage[100];
int currentRoll = 1;
int point = roll2Dice();
int printingNumber = 0;
currentGameStorage[0] = point;
if(point == 7 || point == 11)
{
    crapsResult = true_result;
}
else if(point == 2 || point == 3 || point == 12)
{
    crapsResult = false_result;
}
else
{
    crapsResult = unrolled;
}

while(crapsResult == unrolled)
{
    currentGameStorage[currentRoll] = roll2Dice();
    if(currentGameStorage[currentRoll] == point)
    {
        crapsResult = true_result;
    }
    else if(currentGameStorage[currentRoll] == 7)
    {
        crapsResult = false_result;
    }
    currentRoll += 1;
}
```

*I haven't actually compiled this.

Answer (score 0):

```
while(crapsResult != true || crapsResult != false)
```

equals to

```
while(crapsResult == false || crapsResult == true)
```

.

```
//while(crapsResult == (false || true)) // Don´t matter
```

so as boolean has only false or true

it will always evaluate **true** and equals to this expression

```
while(true)
```

Answer (score 0):

In C and C++, expressions can resolve to true or false based on the following: 0 is `false`, everything else is `true`. The formal definition of C's macros FALSE and TRUE is `#define FALSE 0` and `#define TRUE (!(FALSE))`.

A variable of type bool can either be `true` or `false`. You initialize your `crapsResult` with the value of NULL. NULL is a macro defined as `0UL` or `0ULL`, which evaluates to false.

```
bool crapsResult = NULL;
```

is equivalent to

```
bool crapsResult = false;
```

So when your code does the following:

```
while (crapsResult != true || crapsResult != false)
```

one of these conditions is always met, so the loop always repeats.

You will need a second variable, presumably of type bool, to determine if you have an acceptable answer.

```
bool crapsResult = false;
bool haveCrapsResult = false;
int currentGameStorage[100];
int currentRoll = 1;
int point = roll2Dice();
int printingNumber = 0;
currentGameStorage[0] = point;
if(point == 7 || point == 11)
{
    crapsResult = true;
    haveCrapsResult = true;
}
else if(point == 2 || point == 3 || point == 12)
{
    crapsResult = false;
    haveCrapsResult = false;
}

while(!haveCrapsResult)
{
    currentGameStorage[currentRoll] = roll2Dice();
    if(currentGameStorage[currentRoll] == point)
    {
        crapsResult = true;
        haveCrapsResult = true;
    }
    else if(currentGameStorage[currentRoll] == 7)
    {
        crapsResult = false;
        haveCrapsResult = true;
    }
    currentRoll += 1;
}
currentRoll -= 1;
if(detailPrint == true)
{
    cout << "Game " << currentGame << ": ";
    for(printingNumber = 0; printingNumber <= currentRoll; printingNumber += 1)
    {
        cout << currentGameStorage[printingNumber] << " ";
    }
    if(crapsResult == true)
    {
        cout << "win";
    }
    else /*if(crapsResult == false) is redundant */
    {
        cout << "lose";
    }
    cout << endl;
}
return crapsResult;
```